# How to use Meteor.users.update to inc a variable in a case specific object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, meteor

I need to `inc` a variable within the case specific object in an array in the profile object in the users object/mongo collection. The case specific object's name will equal a local variable, and the I want to `inc` the variable `num` by 1. What would the syntext for this look like?

Comment: If you know your syntax is broken, don't try to use it to explain your problem, instead describe what you want to achieve through regular speech. What property of the profile do you want to increase ? By which amount ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your model looks like but here is an example that may help you.

```
Test=new Mongo.Collection(null);

var id=Test.insert({
  hashtags:[{
    tag:"meteor",
    count:2
  },{
    tag:"javascript",
    count:5
  }]
});

var tag="meteor";

Test.update({
  _id:id,
  "hashtags.tag":tag
},{
  $inc:{
    "hashtags.$.count":1
  }
});

console.log(Test.findOne());
```

In this example, we specify in the query that we're interested in updating only the array item whose tag matches our local variable, then we use mongodb $ positional operator to increase the item count property accordingly.